# SQL Server EXEC with unquoted string parameter is valid?

Tags: sql-server

By accident I called a stored procedure with an unquoted string parameter.  I expected a syntax error as per:

[EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> If the value of a parameter is an object name, *character string,* or qualified by a database name or schema name, the whole name *must be enclosed in single quotation marks*.

but this works:

```
CREATE PROC foobar @a VARCHAR(40) AS BEGIN SELECT @a END
go
EXEC foobar @a = abc
```

Which surprised me!  I tried on SQL Server versions 2008, 2012 and 2016.  Am I missing something or is this just an undocumented "feature"?

Comment: Sounds odd to me too... but I get the same result (tested on `SQL Server 2008 R2`)

Comment: And works for multiple parameters too. File it away with "annoying tricks to confound people with" and possibly "things to consider when trying to find a new angle on SQL injection"

Comment: `foobar abc` on its own would do the same. I can remember a MSDN Connect item relating to this where the conclusion was basically "yes it does this for no specified reason and won't change for compatibility reasons" - but that site is no more.

Comment: Yes, this is one of T-SQL's more awful syntactical oversights. It gets extra fun when you think you can pass things like `GETDATE`. You can, it's just not what you think it is... This also "works" when specifying default values in parameter declarations, and probably in a few more spots where it's not wanted.

Comment: This is pure speculation on my part, but I think this is a result of a lax parsing of object names. That is, making something like `sp_helptext [sp_helptext]` work "naturally" without having to "redundantly" quote the object names as strings (and this syntax is actually still really used in some system stored procedures, so "not removed for compat reasons" is very valid). If we dig really deep we may well find this was already present in the Sybase original.

Comment: Ps. MS are aware and it seems that this is by design: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32902402-are-quoted-identifiers-implicitly-cast-when-passed "SQL Server automatically converts “single-word identifiers” to string literals if they are provided as NVARCHAR parameters in stored procedure calls"

Comment: And what is even more fun is that if the string starts with a number it fails. Or if the string contains a non-numeric character. Such a strange thing that I had not seen in quite a long time.

Comment: @SeanLange: "of course" that fails, such strings aren't valid identifiers. It'll work fine if you escape them: `exec foobar [12 angry men]`. (Hence my speculation about object name parsing.)

Answer (score 6):

MS are aware, and their comments on [this post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32902402-are-quoted-identifiers-implicitly-cast-when-passed) imply that this is by design:

> SQL Server automatically converts “single-word identifiers” to string literals if they are provided as NVARCHAR parameters in stored procedure calls. Therefore these statement will work fine:
>
> ```
> EXEC dbo.TestProc foo
> EXEC dbo.TestProc "foo"
> EXEC dbo.TestProc [foo]
> ```
>
> and they are equivalent to:
>
> ```
> EXEC dbo.TestProc 'foo'
> ```
>
> However, it does not convert identifiers to string literals in SELECT and assignments.

However, I can't think of any situation where it would be appropriate to use this (aside from testing for vulnerabilities which exploit this feature, or in writing code to execute user-provided queries which you wish to provide full language support for, including quirks.

The best advise is to be aware that this is possible (so you don't rule out the possibility of it working when writing tests / debugging code / checking for potential exploits), but do not make use of this behavior in your own code.

Comment: Plus 1 on the advice.  I'd never let it pass in code review.